# Invalid operand size for instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x87

So I'm trying to finish up my averaging program with float numbers, but I'm getting an invalid operand size. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
.386    
.model flat 
public _Average     
.code   

_Average proc
 finit
 mov ecx, [esp + 4]      
 mov ebx, [esp + 8]     
 fldz
 jecxz   Done

Do:
 fadd    REAL8 PTR [ebx]
 add     ebx, 8
 loop    Do
 fidiv   REAL8 PTR [esp + 4]

Done:
ret
_Average endp

.data   
 end
```

Comment: Why not tell us what line the error is on? This is not a "stump the panel" web site. Also, have you considered the possibility that the operand size is invalid?

Answer (score 2):

`FIDIV` divides `ST(0)` by an integer that can be either 16 or 32 bits, but you're trying to pass it a 64-bit operand:

```
fidiv   REAL8 PTR [esp + 4]
```

Use either

```
fidiv   WORD PTR [esp + 4]
```

or

```
fidiv   DWORD PTR [esp + 4]
```

and make sure that the value at `[esp + 4]` is an integer.

Comment: A similar problem probably exists on the first operation. Is ebx really pointing to a float variable?